# Referring to MS Windows special folders in Emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, windows-xp, special-folders

Is there a simple way to find a file on my desktop in Emacs?
Instead of going the "C:\Documents and Settings\MyName\Desktop\" way...

Maybe there is a way to define aliases in my .emacs which I can use during find-file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175982/create-aliases-in-emacs).  I think you may find [bookmarks](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?%28emacs%29Bookmarks) useful, but the linked discussion presents some other options as well.  In addition, [this blog article](http://curiousprogrammer.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/emacs-directory-aliases/) presents a few interesting options, such as `ido-mode` (part of Emacs as of version 22).

Answer (score 1):

I use `%USERPROFILE%` as my home directory, so Desktop is always available as ~/Desktop. Easiest way to do this is to set `HOME` to match `USERPROFILE`. Detailed instructions at:

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2006/12/emacs-hack-1-installing-emacs-on-windows.ashx

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that you can use environment variables in the minibuffer, so `C-x C-f / $USERPROFILE/Desktop` is at least slightly shorter than typing out the whole path.